# Search for records that have unassigned field in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

What is the internal id for 'unassigned'?  I've tried 0, -1, null, but have run out of ideas...

```
    var unassigned = 'WHAT IS IT?';


    var filters = new Array();
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter(nsIds.customerAreas_relatedCustomer, null, 'anyOf', unassigned)); 

    var columns = new Array();
    var nameColumn = new nlobjSearchColumn('name', null);
    columns.push(nameColumn);

    var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_test', null , filters , columns);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter(nsIds.customerAreas_relatedCustomer, null, 'anyOf', '@NONE@'));
```